# Código no se ejecuta o muestra undefined si lo ejecuto por consola

Tags: javascript, funciones, undefined

Tengo el siguiente código:

```js
function recorridoPorI()
{
    for(i=0;i<5;i++)
    {
        console.log("acá i vale:" + i);
    }
   
}
```

Si solo dejo el `for` funciona, pero no es lo que me piden, sí o sí debe estar dentro de esa función. El problema es que no ejecuta nada y, cuando lo pruebo en la consola, muestra `undefined`.

Muchas gracias!!

Answer (score 1):

En la consola te retorna `undefined` es porque no se ha ejecutado o no retorna nada.

para ver el resultado del **for** deberas ejecutar la funcion `recorridoPorI()` *(No olvides los parentesis)*